# Duplicate value in dropdown

Tags: html, django

I am creating a simple 'to do list' app. 1 table of items with a description and 1 of status' where each item can be either incomplete or complete.

I have the following in my html template:

```
<h1> To do list </h1><br>
{% if itemlist %}
    {% for desc in itemlist %}
        <li>{{desc}}<select>
                        {% for status in statuslist %}
                        <option value="{{status.id}}">{{status}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <option selected>{{desc.status}}</option>

                    </select>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p> No Items Found </p>
{% endif %}
```

My problem is populating the dropdown list with both values and automatically showing the value held in the database. With my current code the value that is held is being shown correctly but it is being duplicated in the dropdown so it is showing either:

```
'incomplete'
'complete'
'incomplete'
```

or

```
'incomplete'
'complete'
'complete'
```

instead of

```
'incomplete'
'complete'
```

I tried adding `selected="{{desc.status}}"` to the `<option>` tag but it populates each item with the value of the first.
How do I modify this to reflect what I want to see?

Comment: I used `statuslist = status.objects.distinct()` instead of `statuslist = status.objects.all()` but it returned the same. There values are not duplicated in the status table they only duplicate in the dropdown; I think there is a problem with my syntax in the template? Ultimately I will use a form to post the results back to the db.

Comment: See @Nikhil Doomra's answer.that will solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<h1> To do list </h1><br>
{% if itemlist %}
    {% for desc in itemlist %}
        <li>{{desc}}<select>
                        {% for status in statuslist %}
                           {% if status==desc.status %}
                              <option value="{{status.id}}" selected>{{status}}</option>
                           {% else %}
                              <option value="{{status.id}}">{{status}}</option>
                           {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p> No Items Found </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This partially worked: I used `{% ifequal status desc.status%}` instead of the equality which threw a `Could not parse the remainder` error.

Comment: Actually I didn't know the syntax .. I could tell by looking at your logic :)